# Stack Overflow at java.util.Properties.getProperty

Tags: java, stack-overflow

When running my application, after 40000 transactions getting stack overflow exception at java.util.Properties.getProperty.

Please find below the stack error ..

```
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.Hashtable.get(Hashtable.java:334)
    at java.util.Properties.getProperty(Properties.java:932)
    at java.util.Properties.getProperty(Properties.java:934)
    ... 80,0000 times 
    at java.util.Properties.getProperty(Properties.java:934)
    at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:653)
    at sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction.run(GetPropertyAction.java:67)
    at sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction.run(GetPropertyAction.java:32)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(PrintWriter.java:78)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(PrintWriter.java:62)
    at java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format(SimpleFormatter.java:71)
    at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.publish(FileHandler.java:133)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:481)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:503)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.logp(Logger.java:703)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger.log(Jdk14Logger.java:101)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger.error(Jdk14Logger.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:879)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I'm not able to trace the from where the stack error is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mean to state the obvious, but maybe you should check if you are *creating variables inside the loop* that performs these transactions (the 40.000 repetitions one :-)), instead of reusing the same variable. Also, *checking the constraint inside the loop* can create unnecessary load. *String concatenation* can produce massive load, too. So, if you have something like this:

```
for (i=0; i < getNumberOfTransactions(); i++){      // constraint checking inside the loop 

    int currentValue = myTransaction.getSomeData();  // creating new variable in every 
}
```

You should write something like this instead:

```
int numberOfTransactions = getNumberOfTransactions();
int currentValue = 0;

for(i=0; i < numberOfTransactions; i++){

    currentValue = myTransaction.getSomeData();
}
```

Although this example uses only 2 integer variables, when multiple variables are created inside the loop (especially string concatenation), this can consume a lot of memory. If you have some string concatenation, use *StringBuilder* class instead.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that your test case is running out of memory. A
possible solution would be to increase the memory of the JVM. I
believe the default memory setting for the JVM is 256M or maybe 512M.
This should be sufficient for your test execution. Short term solution
is to use -Xmx1700m (assuming you have the 1.7 gig of memory to
spare).

Comment: Memory shouldn't be problem in my case. Because i have given 5GB for JVM. Below are the options i have passed to JVM.

-XX:ErrorFile=hs_err_pid.log -XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xmx5000m -XX:MaxJavaStackTraceDepth=1000000